# Get Path of PDF Opened in Acrobat DC Pro (Working in VB but not in C#)

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, acrobat-sdk

I just wish to retrieve the path of PDF document opened in Acrobat DC Pro, and save paths to my database in c#,

I able to get active pdf document in c# but unable to retrieve path of the document,

```
Type PDFType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AcroExch.App");
CAcroApp AcroAppObj = Activator.CreateInstance(PDFType) as CAcroApp;  

CAcroAVDoc AvDocObj = AcroAppObj.GetActiveDoc() as CAcroAVDoc;  

CAcroPDDoc PdDocObj = AvDocObj.GetPDDoc() as CAcroPDDoc;

object jsObj = pdDocObj.GetJSObject();
```

Now in **jsObj** I get System.__ComObject, if I am using Vb.net, then I get path of document simply as,

```
Dim docPath As string
docPath = jsObj.path
```

but, it is not allowed in C#, what should I do?

Comment: What if you explicitly use `System.__ComObject` as object type for `jsObj` instead of `object`? Just cast it:

Comment: Unfortunately, There is no such Class/interface called `JSObject` in Adobe SDK, in which I can cast it.

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution to get the path of the current active Doc. It uses Acrobat Form api to get the path via js. Attached a vbs example. Good luck, Reinhard

```
Path = "D:\Test.pdf"

Set App = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")
app.show
Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
Set AForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App") 'from AFormAPI

If AVDoc.Open(Path,"") Then
    '// write some js code on a vbs variable
   js =  "var f = this.path;" &vblf _
        & "app.alert(f);"
     '//execute the js code
    AForm.Fields.ExecuteThisJavaScript js
end if

Set AForm = Nothing
Set AVDoc = Nothing
Set APP = Nothing
```

Comment: Yup, I agree this works, but I need to built up same in c#. Any help?